Dependency on a non-existent service "api_platform.listener.request.deserialize"
I use Insomnia software to test my API with Symfony 7.1.7 and API Platform 4.0.8.
When I send my request, the following error message appears:
The service "App\EventListener\DeserializeListener" has a dependency on a non-existent service "api_platform.listener.request.deserialize".
My DeserializeListener.php:
<?php

namespace App\EventListener;

use ApiPlatform\Symfony\EventListener\DeserializeListener as DecoratedListener;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;

class DeserializeListener
{
    public function __construct(private DecoratedListener $decorated)
    {
    }

    public function onKernelRequest(RequestEvent $event): void
    {
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        if($request->isMethodCacheable() || $request->isMethod(Request::METHOD_DELETE))
        {
            return;
        }

        dd($request->getContent());
    }
}

My services.yaml:
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones
    App\OpenApi\OpenApiFactory:
        decorates: 'api_platform.openapi.factory'
        arguments: ['@App\OpenApi\OpenApiFactory.inner']
        autoconfigure: false

    App\StateProvider\DependenciesStateProvider:
        arguments:
            $rootPath: '%kernel.project_dir%'

    App\StateProcessor\DependenciesStateProcessor:
        arguments:
            $rootPath: '%kernel.project_dir%'

    App\EventListener\DeserializeListener:
        tags:
            - {
                name: 'kernel.event_listener',
                event: 'kernel.request',
                method: 'onKernelRequest',
                priority: 2
            }
        autoconfigure: false
        decorates: 'api_platform.listener.request.deserialize'
        arguments:
            $decorated: '@App\EventListener\DeserializeListener.inner'

When I use autocomplete for "api_platform.listener.request.deserialize", the icon is gray.
I follow a tutorial that's a bit too old.
I tried to put something else for "decorates" but I don't really know what to choose.
How to fix the problem?

add this line use_symfony_listeners: true in file api_platform.yaml
docs : https://api-platform.com/docs/core/events/

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
